# VimbaCPP memory leak

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I'm currently setting up a project with Vimba SDK in Qt.

I followed Vimbas example code but recognized a slow increase of memory usage with time when I capture images and found following line which I think is causing this problem:

```
void AlliedVisionCameras::grabImage(cv::Mat &image){

    FramePtr rpFrame;
    VmbErrorType res;
    uchar* pBuffer;

    m_pCamera->Open(VmbAccessModeFull);
    m_pCamera->AcquireSingleImage( rpFrame, 2000 );
    rpFrame->GetImage(pBuffer);

    image = cv::Mat(m_nHeight,m_nWidth,CV_8UC1,pBuffer) 
}
```

Im pretty sure its because of pBuffer because it never gets deleted but if I use

```
uchar* pBuffer = new uchar;
.
.
delete pBuffer;
```

instead, my program crashes. I dont really know how to free the pointer variable and working with a SmartPointer did not work because the getImage()-Function couldnt handle it.

Anyone has an idea?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Isn't pBuffer supposed to be an array? You should declare its size, and then delete it with delete[]. According to http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/avt_vimba_camera/html/Frame_8h_source.html you can get the image size with VmbErrorType GetImageSize( VmbUint32_t &imageSize )

Comment: No, it looks like the frame owns the image. The GetImage function takes the pointer *by reference* and modifies it: http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/avt_vimba_camera/html/Frame_8cpp_source.html#l00229

Comment: SetupFrame allocates the frame: http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/avt_vimba_camera/html/Camera_8cpp_source.html#l00138  I'm not sure what a NetPointer is, so I don't know if you can just `delete rpFrame` though...

Comment: rpFrame is a SmartPointer so it should delete itself after running out of scope, right?

Comment: Is it? I didn't see that in the docs above, but if so, I would expect you're right. I'm not sure, I was just reading through the code to see what it does, and I suggest you do the same if you can't find an answer easily :)